# is not null is not working properly

Tags: php, mysql

I want to retrieve data from a table with column name which is not null.When I use IS NOT NULL it is selecting all the rows.please check my code.

```
my table is 
------------------------------------------------------
 i_am                  pname                     name
------------------------------------------------------
 cardiologist                                     dbkr
 orthopedician                                    mdv
                       apollo                     mbkr
 pateint                                          charan
```

Now I want to retrieve the data from the table where pname is not null and show that list in a select box.So I am writing the following code

```
<select name="pharmacy" id="pharmacy">
<?php
$sqlPh = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE pname IS NOT NULL";
$mysqlPh = mysqli_query($con,$sqlPh);
//die(mysqli_num_rows($mysqlPh));
while($phData = mysqli_fetch_object($mysqlPh))
{
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $phData->pname;?>"><?php echo $phData->pname;?></option>

<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

What I am expecting is

```
<select>
    <option value="apollo">apollo</option>
</select>
```

But what it is giving is

```
<select>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option value="apollo">apollo</option>
    <option></option>
</select>
```

Where it is giving null values too.How to get not null values only?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that those records appearing to have empty values in the `pname` column actually do not have `NULL` but rather have whitespace.  If so, you could workaround this using the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE COALESCE(TRIM(pname), '') <> '';
```

Answer (score 1):

Some columns may have empty whitespace while other have null 
try this

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `pname` != ''
```

this will only get values which have some data

above will produce what you want but to be more precise use this below query

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `pname` IS NOT NULL AND `pname` != ''
```

here you are getting data which is not null and not empty

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE TRIM(pname) <> '';
```